# Two C++ classes with methods that return the other

Tags: c++, class

I have to classes, a and b, each needs to have a method that returns the other. If I try to compile the following code, I get an error for not defining the latter class ahead:

```
class a{
public:
    b* change(){
        return new b;
    }
}
class b{
public:
    a* change(){
        return new a;
    }
}
```

`error: 'b' does not name a type`

I understand why, of course, but I want to know if there's a way to implement it correctly.

Comment: Could you tell us what in particular you want to do? Such a circular dependency may very well be a design mistake.

Comment: @Arkadiy That question is not a duplicate at all. It only answers half of this question.

Comment: @Maxim: I've read through this duplicate and the answers talk both about forward declaration and out-of-class function bodies.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, this is a different duplicate now, high quality one.

Comment: It's not a mistake, I want a program that uses a class with a chain of methods, and these dependencies are required in order to swap type, kind of like a state machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the definitions of methods after the declarations of classes:

```
class b;
class a{
public:
    b* change();
}
class b{
public:
    a* change();
}

b* a::change() { return new b; }
a* b::change() { return new a; }
```

In other words, when you do `new T`, the *definition* of `T` must be available.

Comment: I'd be pedantic and spell out the 2 things you've shown are required: forward-declaration of the classes to provide incomplete types for the method declarations, and full declaration of the classes to provide complete types for constructing (incidentally to return). The requirement for forward-declarations is left implicit in your answer, but it's absolute.

Comment: @underscore_d Be my guest and edit.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly,. make an object of class b, and then call it.
i.e.
class b;
and then call it in class a.

Comment: What do you mean? Please show some code illustrating what you're trying to say. _Call_ has 2 possible, very different meanings here, and I think you're getting them mixed up.